# Force Chrome to keep history longer than 10 weeks

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, history

I am looking for a way to have Chrome keep my history for longer than 10 weeks. The main functionality I am looking for is the ability to see hyperlinks displayed in purple for websites that I've already visited. However, websites that I've visited longer than 10 weeks ago will not show as purple links because the history gets purged. I've tried searching a lot of different keywords but can't find an answer to this problem.

I am aware of certain extensions that allow you to view your old history, but they do not preserve the purple hyperlink color because the file is stored separately from Chrome's history.

I was told to ask this question here as opposed to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Does this extension [History Trends Unlimited](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-trends-unlimited/pnmchffiealhkdloeffcdnbgdnedheme) help?

Comment: That is the extension I was referring to. It saves the old history, but does so in a separate location, thus the purple hyperlinks are not preserved. I discussed it with the dev that created it and he said he doesn't know of a way to accomplish what I'm asking for. Thanks for looking though!

Answer (score -1):

Sign in to Chrome, and it should sync all of your history. I have a dual-boot Windows/Linux laptop, an android phone and another Windows laptop each with the same Chrome account signed in and I have history since the start of 2013 (when I began using Chrome).

Comment: Chrome doesn't keep any history after 10 weeks.
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/3e-fR2KVLcw